# Grails : id generator using assigned and falling back to sequence if unassigned

Tags: grails, grails-orm, auto-increment, database-sequence

I am working with Grails 3.2.8. I would like to allow both options when generating an id. Is there a way to use assigned and falling back to sequence if unassigned? I tried getting the next id within a constructor and setting id there but running into issues. Any help/guidance would be most appreciated.

```
class Foo {
  static mapping = {
    id generator:'assigned'
  }
}
```

vs

```
class Foo {
  static mapping = {
    id generator:'sequence'
  }
}
```

Ive tried using mapping set to `assigned` and setting the id within the domain constructor of `beforeValidate` function. Neither are working for me. Examples below.

```
class Foo{
    Foo(){          
        def id = Foo.find("from Foo order by id desc")
        id = id ? id : 0
        this.id = id
    }
    static mapping = {
        id generator:'assigned'
    }
}

class Foo{
    def beforeValidate() {
        def id = Foo.find("from Foo order by id desc")
        id = id ? id : 0
        this.id = id
    }
    static mapping = {
        id generator:'assigned'
    }
 }
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to use assigned and falling back to sequence if
>   unassigned?

No, not directly anyway.  You could use `assigned` and when you wanted to fall back on the sequence you could send a query to the database to retrieve the next sequence value and then assign it yourself.  I think that is probably as close as you can probably get.

Comment: Updated the question. If possible, could you give an example. Ive tried using the constructor and the `beforeValidate` function. Ive also tried using `beforeInsert`, I run into issues when using any of these. Thank you for your time Mr. Brown.

Comment: You have changed your question to be a wholly different question now.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to understand `HQL`; in your examples you are returning `Foo` not `id`, so it's clearly wrong.

Second, you shouldn't depend on the `table` for next value of `id`, because it's not guaranteed to be correct -- you might face `id` is not unique kinda errors.

Third, you aren't incrementing the `id`, this way you will end up getting the same, most likely `0`, every time.

Here is what you can do, use database `sequence` -- depends on the database.

```
"select id_seq.nextval from dual" // for Oracle
```

Finally, it's a very bad idea -- unless you are having a very good reason for it.